# Windows XP pro - Android file sharing without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, android, file-transfer, sp3

I want to share files between my android device & windows xp pro sp3 computer.
**Wireless and without internet.**

In Windows:

I created a network for file sharing via the "network setup wizard" and check the option "this computer cannot access the internet".
After rebooting , i can see that file sharing is enabled(it appears a new "file sharing" folder). In the last step, the wizard ask me to create or not a network setup disk so that others computers can connect,but since it concern android i checked no.

In Android:

There are several apps about file sharing but they all need to access internet by wifi.

Comment: Windows XP does not have a native feature that support sharing a file with an Android device.  This means you need to find and install a third-party application that adds this capability.

Comment: does windows machine posess a wireless card?

Comment: @Ramhound: this "third-party application" always need to access internet wifi .

Comment: @xavier_fakerat: yes.

Comment: @user-707 - Yes;  If you want to share a device with an Android device that is connected to your network through a wireless connection, your PC will also have to be connected to your network through a wireless connection.  You can't change that factoid.

Comment: @Ramhound: Someone could set a WLAN without internet .The problem is that android file-transfer apps required internet.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have done on Windows XP so far has been useless. Sure, there is an Android app called ES File Explorer that can access SMB/Samba shares on Windows, but not when you have run that awful Network Setup Wizard, which belongs to 1990s. This "wizard" (for which "muggle" is a more fitting name) activates what is known as Simple File Sharing. This Wizard does not allow Android to authenticate properly with Windows XP. (Read more about it in: ["How to use the Simple File Sharing feature to share files in Windows XP"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304040/how-to-use-the-simple-file-sharing-feature-to-share-files-in-windows-xp). *Support*. Microsoft. 19 July 2014.)

Your best bet is to resort to Wi-Fi file sharing apps like [Zapya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapya) or [SHAREit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHAREit). You install their clients on both Android and Windows and use them to exchange files. (Zapya on Windows can exchange file with Zapya on Android. SHAREit on Windows can exchange files with SHAREit on Android.)

Comment: first of all,thanks for the info about xp,then about those 2 android apps,they ask for a lot of personal data to install.Maybe not in older versions but how do we know since google play store propose the new versions only ?

Comment: @user-707 Provide none. Registration with them is optional. You don't need to sign up, unless you want to.

Comment: What do you mean by "sign up",to google or apps ? maybe i wasn't clear enough,if you click on "install" those apps on google store,to install those apps ask to access a lot of personnal data in the phone,which isn't the case for some others apps.

Comment: @user-707 It seems you are either referring to the app's required permissions or information that Google gathers. The app, of course, requires a lot of permissions because it needs to do a lot of things. e.g. sending and receiving contacts needs permission to access contacts. Same for photos. ... But without these apps, you are out of luck.